# Ebay API - Shopping API - GetShippingCosts: No HTTPS Support?

Tags: ebay-api

I am currently using the GetShippingCosts call from the Shopping API and trying to convert all calls to https but it seems that https is not supported ?

I do not want to use the Trading API as from what I have read, it looks like I have to provide an authentication token and its SOAP and XML only - I am getting the shipping costs from requests by the user browser not through the server so the authentication token would be visible in Javascript. Also do not want a user authentication token.

Are there any alternatives, maybe I'm missing something ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.